# Does Vangelico have any competitors?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

So I'm about to do the mission where I rob Vangelico. Before I go, I'm wondering if they have any competitors whose stocks I can buy. I can't find any info about this online - maybe not all companies have competitors?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are only a few single-player missions that effect the in-game stock market, and they're mostly concentrated around the Lester assassination missions.  The companies involved in the heists, including Vangelico, do not appear to have any useful/exploitable effect on the market.

The advice I followed to track the events that effect the market in single player is [on this page](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1VLK0HCFWmfb7uG4_tzurGGBVY1WZBxF-2iKRwNojZRs/viewform).  Lester does a pretty good job of informing you how to invest during these missions, though.  If you wait until after the final heist to do as many of these missions as you can, you stand to make a pretty good profit.

Comment: Heists have to have an effect on the market. I checked Vangelico's price immediately before the heist, it was 250. Immediately afterwards it was 150.

Comment: @victoriah, ah, I edited to clarify.  I meant there was no effect for the purposes of exploiting the stock market by virtue of your insider knowledge that they are going to be robbed.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, there are multiple ways to tinker with the stock market in free-roam. Help you get up to the $150 mil and more. The most known of ways is: Invest in Augury Insurance. Then destroy some people's cars. Then cash in on the now-valuable stocks. I suggest using a tank then going into rush hour/big streets. you might get into trouble, but all you must do is make it to the train tracks by Lester's building, and away with ye. You can escape 5 stars on a train. As well as survive much. There are other ways to manipulate stocks though. By investing in one company, say Taco Bomb, and destroyed a CluckinBell store, you will raise the Taco Bomb stocks. I should also mention BAWSAQ is run with SC (Social Club). If SC is down, so it BAWSAQ. And every stock you can manipulate in offline, or free-roam, is on LCN. LCN is entirely offline/reliant on your characters. BAWSAQ prices are determined by the entirety of GTA 5 online players (Those connected to SC). I hope I helped.